# Could we rename [cmd.exe] to [windows-command-prompt]?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, retag-request

Microsoft refers to their standard command line interface as '[Command Prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7)', yet our tag for it calls it by it's filename, [cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cmd.exe).

It's also inconsistent with how we have other CLIs and shells named, which use their correct names (such as [bash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bash), [sh](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sh), [powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell) etc). I suggest [cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cmd.exe) be renamed to [windows-command-prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-command-prompt)*

*I would suggest [command-prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-prompt) by itself, however I feel this would be abused as a catch-all for **any** command prompt application. Thus for our own sanity's sake we should stick '*windows*' in front of it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, we probably should do that now. I'll try to remember to look into it tonight.

Comment: @Oliver - sorry, didn't realise it was suggested before. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: Heheh, thanks for looking out for bad tags ;)